# Order by in both sides of union

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need to order by `city` both sides of the `union` query:

```
select * from( select top(1)city, len(city) from Station    
where len(city) = (select min(len(d.city)) from Station d ) order by city ) as a
union all select * from  (select top(1) city, LEN(city) from Station 
 where len(city) = (select max(len(f.city)) from station f) order by city ) as b
```

I need to order both sides because if I have two cities with the same length then I need to get the first in alphabetical order, and if I put the `order by` at the end of the whole query it will not do what I want, if you have another way to do this I will appreciate suggestions..

When I run this query I'm getting this error:

```
Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
No column name was specified for column 2 of 'a'.
Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 4
No column name was specified for column 2 of 'b'.
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from ( select top(1) city, len(city) as 'length' 
                from Station    
                order by len(city) asc, city ) as a
union all 
select * from ( select top(1) city, len(city) as 'length' 
                from Station    
                order by len(city) desc, city ) as b
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed

```
select * from( select top(1)city, len(city) as 'length' from Station    
where len(city) = (select min(len(d.city)) from Station d ) order by city ) as a
union all select * from  (select top(1) city, LEN(city) as 'length' from Station 
 where len(city) = (select max(len(f.city)) from station f) order by city ) as b
```

Comment: I realized that I should put a name for the column len(city), that's whay the error was taking place :)

Answer (score 0):

Specify column first for len(city)

like `len(city) as lencity`

and don't order by in both statements,it doesn't make any difference..Its the final order by that matters.. and order by is not required in aggregates

So your statement can be..

```
select * from( select top(1)city, len(city) as lencity
 from Station    
where len(city) = (select min(len(d.city)) from Station d ) ) as a
union all 
select * from  (select top(1) city, LEN(city) as lencity from Station 
 where len(city) = (select max(len(f.city)) from station f)  ) as b
order by lencity
```

Comment: With the query that I put I get : abc 3 and Edmonton 8, is what I need to get, with yours I'm getting def 3 and Edmonton 8 Do you see the difference? When I have two cities with the same length I need to make my decision according to the alphabetical order.. thanks